# Visual C++ pass reference to static array

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use the following code :

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE keyAttrTemplate[] = {
    { CKA_SUBJECT , NULL , 0 },
    { CKA_LABEL, NULL, 0}
};

flist->C_GetAttributeValue(h1, keys[2], &keyAttrTemplate, 2);
```

inspired from the following code (taken in the PKCS#11 documentation) :

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE template[] = {
    {CKA_MODULUS, NULL_PTR, 0},
    {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, NULL_PTR, 0}
};
CK_RV rv;
rv = C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, hObject, &template,2);
//C_GetAttributeValue prototype :
//CK_RV C_GetAttributeValue(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession,CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject, CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR pTemplate, CK_ULONG ulCount)
```

but Visual Studio 2015 is giving me the following error message when i try to compile:

> argument of type "CK_ATTRIBUTE(*)[2]" is incompatible with parameter of type "CK_ATTRIBTUE_PTR"

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: For starters, `template` is a keyword. Or are you compiling this as C?

Comment: Try without applying the address-of operator on the array.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: In the C++ language, yes. The PKCS#11 API in written in C, and thus is "template" not such a bad variable name choice for a CK_ATTRIBUTE array which defines parameters to be retrieved in a research.

Comment: Try to remove the ampersand from the `&template`. I currently don't have a time to check this so I don't put it as an answer.

Comment: @Marian Spanik: Thanks ! post it as answer anytime you want. But for my personal curiosity, why has the '&' in C++ ?

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in the documentation, and it should say either `template` or `&template[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove CKA_MODULUS template on Private/public Key Attributes.
Re-initialize attributes

Anil Nandey